# ng has unexpectedly closed giving the error 127.why this happens?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

I'm trying to build an app from a script.But,while trying to run "ionic serve".It shows the errors like this:

[error] Error: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.

```
at Observable._subscribe (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\experimental\jobs\simple-scheduler.js:350:23)

at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)

at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)

at C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31

at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)

at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54)

at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)

at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)

at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)

at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)

at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)

at C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28

at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)

at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54

at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)

at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\Food Grocery  Meat Delivery Mobile App with Admin Panel V2.0\Ionic Mobile App Code\Foodland_user\foodlands_user_v2.0\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. Try downgrading it to a specific version like so:

`npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24` should work fine :)

More info [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16902#issuecomment-590069541)